# Why the Shift + Enter shortcut does not send my Python code to the interactive window?

Tags: python-interactive

I am trying to write a Python Script in VSCode, and I want to use the interactive window comes with the Jupyter Extention in the process of writing.

I tried to use the `Shift + Enter` shortcut to run the selected code in the interactive window like the suggestion here but it does not work.

[This is what VSCode shows me when I right click the selected code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqOQX.png)

Instead, the code is sent & run in the terminal. I can only run the selected code in the interactive window when I use my mouse to click in the option show in the picture above.

I've found the the `Shift + Enter` shortcut is also the shortcut for run the selected code in the terminal. So I have tried to change the shortcut for running the code in the interactive window to something else. I also tried to restart my machine & relaunch VSCode but it still does not work.